# How do I translate "context"?

Tags: translation, grammar, usage

是不是可以说：

> 在这上下文，这个生词不可以这样用。

还有，

> You've taken it entirely out of context.

或者比如有学生问老师个问题，可是问提不太清楚，老师会回答说：

> Can you give provide some context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Context' stands for the 'environment' / 'background' that an object or event lives in.

> It could be translated differently depending on **context**.
>   它可以依照**语境**来作具体翻译.

..

> 在这**上下文**，这个生词不可以这样用。
>   / 在当前**上下文**，这个生词不可以像这样用。

Remarks: In modern Chinese '这' rarely appears alone instead of '这儿' '这里' '这样' '此'.

..

> You've taken it entirely **out of context**.
>   你完全**脱离了背景范畴**. / 你过于**断章取义**了. /你过于**片面**了.

..

> Can you give provide some **context**?
>   可以提供一些**相关背景**吗?

Comment: out of context 断章取义 for example sentences see iciba，there also find 脱离上下文、没有上下文、割裂地
provide a context 提供上下文

Comment: About writing, article, etc, we can use '语境'.

Comment: @S.Rhee
语境 is the most strict equivalent, since 'context' is used in many specific disciplines where they actually translate so.